# removing duplicate words in a row

Tags: r, duplicates, strsplit

I have a column in table as below

```
    Col1
    ========================
    "No","No","No","No","No"
    "No","No","No"
     Yes
     No
    "Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes"
    "Yes","No","Yes", "Yes
```

I am trying to remove duplicate No and Yes and create column like this

```
            Col1
    ========================
     No
     No
     Yes
     No
     Yes
     Yes, No
```

I started with

```
     kickDuplicates <- c("No","Yes")
     # create a list of vectors of place names
     broken <- strsplit(Table1$Col1, ",")
     # paste each broken vector of place names back together
     # .......kicking out duplicated instances of the chosen names
     Table1$Col1 <- sapply(broken, FUN = function(x)  paste(x[!duplicated(x)  
     | !x %in% kickDuplicates ], collapse = ", "))
```

But this is not working, i get the same original column with duplicates as before, can anybody tell me where I am going wrong ?

```
c("\"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\"", 
"\"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"Yes\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\"", 
"\"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\"", 
"\"No\", \"No\"", "\"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\", \"No\"", 
"No")
```

Comment: Can you show a `dput(Table1)`?

Comment: You're probably looking for `base::unique` but as David suggests, it's impossible to tell without knowing something about how your data look.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Matthew updated the question with dput from this column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work as your final line:

```
Table1$Col1 <- sapply(broken,function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse=','))
```

Because I am a fan of package `functional`, here is an equivalent:

```
sapply(broken, Compose(unique, Curry(paste, collapse=',')))
```

Comment: Don't think so. Did you see the `dput`? Pretty messed up data set. I wonder where they got it from.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg , David Actually I changed the `strsplit(Table1$Col1, ",")` to `strsplit(Table1$Col1, ",\\s*")` and used what what Matthew suggested and it worked