# How to remove duplicated words in csv rows in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am working with csv file and I have many rows that contain duplicated words and I want to remove any duplicates (I also don't want to lose the order of the sentences).

csv file example (userID and description are the columns name):

```
userID, description

12, hello world hello world

13, I will keep the 2000 followers same I will keep the 2000 followers same

14, I paid $2000 to the car I paid $2000 to the car I paid $2000 to the car

.

.
```

I would like to have the output as:

```
userID, description

12, hello world 

13, I will keep the 2000 followers same

14, I paid $2000 to the car 

.

.
```

I already tried the post such as [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741564/removing-duplicate-rows-from-a-csv-file-using-a-python-script) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687966/removing-duplicate-words-in-a-row) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481088/how-can-i-tell-if-a-string-repeats-itself-in-python) but none of them fixed my problem and did not change anything. (Order for my output file matters, since I don't want to lose the orders). It would be great if you can provide your help with a code sample that I can run in my side and learn. 
Thank you

[I am using python 3.7 version]

Comment: Please format your code/data.

Comment: @VictorHugoBorges sure. thanks. please let me know if now look ok.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell if a string repeats itself in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481088/how-can-i-tell-if-a-string-repeats-itself-in-python)

Comment: @RickyKim I already check that post and it is not answering to my question. I already included as reference in this post (#3)

Comment: @Bilgin see my answer. it works for the 3 examples you provided

Answer (score 2):

To remove duplicates, I'd suggest a solution involving the OrderedDict data structure:

```
df['Desired'] = (df['Current'].str.split()
                          .apply(lambda x: OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys())
                          .str.join(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me:

```
a = pd.Series(["hello world hello world", 
               "I will keep the 2000 followers same I will keep the 2000 followers same",
               "I paid $2000 to the car I paid $2000 to the car I paid $2000 to the car"])
a.apply(lambda x: " ".join([w for i, w in enumerate(x.split()) if x.split().index(w) == i]))
```

Basically the idea is to, for each word, only keep it if its position is the first in the list (splitted from string using space). That means, if the word occurred the second (or more) time, the `.index()` function will return an index smaller than the position of current occurrence, and thus will be eliminated.

This will give you:

```
0                            hello world
1    I will keep the 2000 followers same
2                I paid $2000 to the car
dtype: object
```

Comment: Your code would give a wrong answer to "I will keep the 2000 followers the same I will keep the 2000 followers the same" (notice that there are 2 `the`'s in the sentence.)

Comment: @Yilun Zhang Thanks for your comments and code. If I modify your code as: `data = pd.read_csv('someCSv.csv', error_bad_lines=False);
a = pd.Series(data)
a.apply(lambda x: " ".join([w for i, w in enumerate(x.split()) if x.split().index(w) == i]))`  I am getting `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2`. Can you modify your code to do with input csv and then save it to csv. (I am new in python!)

Comment: @Bilgin instead of `a=pd.Series(data)`, try `data['description']`

Comment: @QuangHoang Good point, I will need to revisit it to see how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481088/how-can-i-tell-if-a-string-repeats-itself-in-python):

```
def principal_period(s):
    i = (s+s).find(s, 1)
    return s[:i]

df['description'].apply(principal_period)
```

Output:

```
0                                 hello world
1     I will keep the 2000 followers the same
2                     I paid $2000 to the car
Name: description, dtype: object
```

Since this uses `apply` on string, it might be slow.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried your code as : ` import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('some.csv', error_bad_lines=False);
def principal_period(s):
    i = (s+s).find(s, 1, -1)
    return None if i == -1 else s[:i]
k = data['description'].apply(principal_period) ` and i am getting output as: ` 0    None
1    None
2    None
Name: description, dtype: object`. Can you please modify your code in a wat that takes the input as csv and output csv. (i am new in python) thanks

Comment: Sorry, check update. The function should just `return s[:i]`

Comment: thanks for your code. Now i am using `import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('input.csv', error_bad_lines=False);
def principal_period(s):
    i = (s+s).find(s, 1, -1)
    return s[:i]
k = data['description'].apply(principal_period)` but it is not removing dublicates in my side. Can you please check my code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer taken from [How can I tell if a string repeats itself in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481088/how-can-i-tell-if-a-string-repeats-itself-in-python)

```
import pandas as pd
def principal_period(s):
    s+=' '
    i = (s + s).find(s, 1, -1)
    return None if i == -1 else s[:i]
df=pd.read_csv(r'path\to\filename_in.csv')
df['description'].apply(principal_period)
df.to_csv(r'output\path\filename_out.csv')
```

Explanation:

I have added a space at the end to account for that the repeating strings are delimited by space. Then it looks for second occurring string (minus first and last character to avoid matching first, and last when there are no repeating strings, respectively) when the string is added to itself. This efficiently finds the position of string where the second occuring string starts, or the first shortest repeating string ends. Then this repeating string is returned.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @BryceHowitson added explanation